# Assign shortcut to Visual Studio "Find All"

Tags: visual-studio-2013, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I assign a keyboard shortcut to the "Find All" button of the Quick Find function in Visual Studio 2013?

[image: VS Find All]

I can't find any command that would match this button next to the `Edit.Find...` commands:

[image: VS Keyboard options]

Comment: Did you try Edit.FindAllReferences? Shown in your image below Edit.Find

Comment: @Jenn Yes, this is not what I'm looking for. This is searching for all symbol references.

Comment: A suggestion to do this is "under review". You might like to upvote it here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Find-all-keyboard-shortcut/1470817

Answer (score 43):

I've been looking for the same exact thing! This isn't the best way but this is what I do:

Press `Ctrl + Shift + F`

Type Your Search

Press `Alt + A` (This performs a Find All)

Comment: I agree with the OPs decision not to mark this as accepted.  By default this will find all in the entire solution.  What the op is looking for is to find all in the current file.  While you can still use the Find and Replace window and change the search scope to current document, this is no quicker than doing it via the quick find window.  A shortcut to perform a search in the current document is different, and would be useful.  I use them both.

Comment: @Ian the search scope can be changed once and stays changed. This is much quicker than using quick find

Answer (score 5):

I found it is easiest to re-assign `Edit.FindinFiles` to `Alt + F` then use `Alt + A` to press Find All on that dialog box:

Highlight the text

Press `Alt + F`

Press `Alt + A`

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `Edit.FindinFiles`

It will open a new window every time, but it will provide you with the exact same functionality you desire.

Comment: This is the same as proposed by @adamtoakley, and not this is not what I'm looking for. I want to use the *Quick find* window, and not the *Find and replace* window.

Comment: Sadly I think Microsoft removed it as an option in favor of a new window. :/